# Prove or Disprove: There exists positive integers $x, y, z$, such that $x^8-y^5=z^3$

Tags: solution-verification

$x^8-y^5=z^3$

I believe it is some form of a Diophantine equation but since each variable is to a different power, I am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

We can get examples using powers of $2$, and exploiting the fact that $2^n-2^{n-1}=2^{n-1}$.  We just need $n$ such that $8\,|\,n$ and $15\,|\,(n-1)$.

We see that $$2^{16}-2^{15}=2^{15}\implies (2^2)^8-(2^3)^5=(2^5)^3$$

for instance.

In this way we get an infinite family of solutions, given by $n\equiv 16\pmod {120}$.  Of course, these are not all the solutions.  If $(a,b,c)$ is a solution then so is $(m^{15}a, m^{24}b, m^{40}c)$ for any $m\in \mathbb N$.  I don't know if there are any solutions in which the three integers are relatively prime.

Comment: Other  solutions include $(a,b,c) = (3^{4},\; 3^{6},\; 2 \cdot 3^{10})$ and $(a,b,c) = (2^{3}\cdot 3^{2},\; 2^{5}\cdot 3^{3},\; 2^{8}\cdot 3^{5})$.